# Copying 1 set of Form Entries to another form with different entries

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a web page that has 2 forms on it. The first one comes from another page and has brought information from a database. 
The second form needs that information copied into some of the entries but not all. 
Also, the forms inputs have different names.

Here is the first form:

```
<form name="kmp" id="form1" method="post" action="">
                <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="command" VALUE="search">
                <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="file" VALUE="Repair_Project\RepairProjectWeb.db">
                <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="database" VALUE="SNumber">
                <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="postfields" VALUE="SN_No;SN_Device0;SN_DD0">
                <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="searchfields" VALUE="SN_No">
                <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="AD_Code" VALUE="[[SN_No]]">
                    <TABLE>
                        <TR>
                        <TD>Serial Number: </TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD><input type="text" size="20" name="SN_No"</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                        <TD>Device: </TD><TD></TD><TD><input type="text" size="20" name="SN_Device0"</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                        <TD>Date Dispatched: </TD><TD></TD><TD><input type="text" size="20" name="SN_DD0"</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                        <TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD>
                        </TR>
                    </TABLE>
                </form>
```

Here is the second form:

```
<form name="kmp" id="form2" method="post" action="submit2.html">
                <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="command" VALUE="search">
                <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="file" VALUE="Repair_Project\RepairProjectWeb.db">
                <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="database" VALUE="Repair">
                <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="postfields" VALUE="RP_SNo;RP_Device;RP_DD;RP_Code;RP_SDate;RP_Problem">
                    <TABLE>
                        <TR>
                        <TD>Account Code: </TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD><input type="text" size="20" name="RP_Code"</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                        <TD>Serial Number: </TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD><input type="text" size="20" name="RP_SNo"</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                        <TD>Device: </TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD><input type="text" size="20" name="RP_Device"</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                        <TD>Date Dispatched: </TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD><input type="text" size="20" name="RP_DD"</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                        <TD>Request Date: </TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD><input type="date" size="20" name="RP_SDate"</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                        <TD>Problem: </TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD><input type="text" size="20" name="RP_Problem"</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                        <TD></TD>
                        <TD></TD>
                        <TD class="copy"><input TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="b1" VALUE="Submit Repair Request"></TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                        <TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD>
                    </TABLE>
                </form>
```

I've been trying to use JavaScript to copy the values: SN_No, SN_Device0 and SN_DD0 into the second forms: RP_SNo, RP_Device and RP_DD.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy it by iterating throuh form elements like below

```
var elementsFrom = document.getElementById("form1").elements;//form 1 elements
var formTo = document.getElementById("form2");//form2
for (var i = 0; i < elementsFrom.length; i++) {     
    var el = elementsFrom[i];
    if (el.type === 'text') {//filter the one you interested based on type etc
        formTo.elements.namedItem(el.id).value = el.value;//assign value to form2 element with name el.id
    }
}
```